# Equivalent to Float Left and Overflow Hidden

Tags: css, css-float

I have a little Bootstrap/Font-Awesome alert that looks like this:

[image: Free shipping when you sign up for auto delivery]

The HTML for it looks like this (I inlined the custom CSS just to ask my question):

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <i class="fa fa-check" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"></i>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">{{ $discount }}</p>
</div>
```

This is the exact look that I want, with the checkmark in its own "column" so that the text does not wrap underneath.

This HTML/CSS works totally fine as is, but just to be curious, I tried to accomplish the same layout by changing the `<i>` tag CSS from `float: left` to `display: inline-block`. However, this caused the whole block of text to wrap underneath the checkmark. Is there another way to accomplish the layout in my screenshot without using floats?

---

Edit:

I just tried giving both the `<p>` and `<i>` tags `display: inline-block`, but that didn't work. It caused the `<p>` text to wrap underneath the `<i>` icon.

I put together a jsfiddle right here to play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/9c7ym3sk

Comment: Add `display: inline-block` in both `i` and `p` element.

Comment: It looks good in your fiddle link as your expected image. Check how it looks in my screen http://i.stack.imgur.com/byzWn.png

Comment: Yeah, the fiddle looks fine. I was just curious to see if there was a way to do it without floats. I'm always looking for multiple ways of doing things :)

Comment: Check my answer. there is another way you can do it

Comment: Once you issue solved. Don't forgot to accept any of the answer which solve your issue by clicking on right symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. like following:

```
.alert{
  display: table;
}

.fa{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}
p{
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c7ym3sk/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

By default `<i>` is an inline element while `<p>` is a block level element which takes full width of the browser window. If you set `<i>` as inline-block then subsequent block level element i.e `<p>` will drop in next row so you need to set inline-block property on `p` too.
In another way you can use float: left on `<i>` and overflow: hidden on `<p>`. It will also work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Add some max-width to `<p>` and `vertical-align: top;` to both elements like this.
http://prntscr.com/a6ten4
When content inside `<p>` becomes too much then it causes `<p>` to drop below.
So apply max-width to prevent this...